# Table view implementation in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

[image]

Hello i am beginner , i need to implement table view using jquery mobile .can you please provide some example of table view having header .

Thanks
Naveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry abt the last post. I didnt quite see the image.

For the image you've put up, you could use a `controlgroup` and `h1` inside a `data-role="header"` `div`. Here's a sample

```
 <div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
     <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" id="hdr">My Cases</h1>
    <div class="ui-btn-right" id="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b">Edit</a> //add extra buttons here
    </div>
</div>
```

Using a `control-group` type container will wrap ur buttons into a single entity and allows for more flexibility. if you dont want to use control group use `data-inline="true"` on the buttons. For more info, go here :  [for buttons](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/buttons/),[for headers](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/demos/widgets/headers/)

Demo  : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/W7NcY/5/</kbd>

**EDIT**

adding `style="text-align:left;margin-left: 10px;"` inline does the trick. if you're adding these styles to a `css` file use `!important;` after the style to stop jQM from over writing it.

Demo : <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/W7NcY/7/</kbd>

Comment: As show in Figure there show be a first header ?

Comment: How to show header "My case" with three buttons.

Comment: @NaveenSharma check my updated answer. I saw table and i started typing out code for a table

Comment: that is awesome  can you please tell me how set my case label on left side?

Comment: Header label is on left side

Comment: sorry i am new in jquery mobile that why i am asking

Comment: pls mark the answer if u think this has helped you.. also, upvote if u think this will help others :)

Comment: Hi there is problem when i run this code on browser (chrome). it does not show  add and setting button as shown in fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31707/discussion-between-passionatecoder-and-naveen-sharma)